# operator overloading with complex numbers

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'd like to overload the * operator, so that it will multiply complex subvariables of a class and return the complex result. My idea was the following:

```
#include <complex>

using namespace std; 

class a{
public:
  std::complex<double> x0;
...
};

template<class T> complex<T>  operator*(const a &lfv, const a &rfv){
  return lfv.x0*rfv.x0;
}
```

But it doesn't work... Any ideas or comments?

Comment: *How* it doesn't work? What are the symptoms? And what's the purpose of class `a`, exactly? And why do you use `using namespace std;` to then write `std::complex`?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a sufficient error description.

Comment: Why do you need the tempate argument with your operator? Your class is not template, so returning a complex<double> is sufficient...

Comment: In your template function, the type `T` is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class holds `std::complex<double>` data members and is not a template. You need a non-template function:

```
std::complex<double> operator*(const a& lfv, const a& rfv){
  return lfv.x0*rfv.x0;
}
```

In your example, there is no way for your template function to deduce the return type from the arguments passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Complex class already takes care of that, i.e. it always returns complex result after multiplication.

The usage is as follows:

```
complex<double> p(10,20);
complex<double> q(2,3);
std::cout << p*q << endl;
```

output is:

```
(-40,70)
```

---

OR if you can do it like :

```
class a{
public:
  std::complex<double> x0;
};

complex<double>  operator*(const a &lfv, const a &rfv){
  return lfv.x0*rfv.x0;
}

int main()
{
    a  y;
    y.x0 = complex<double>(10,20);
    a  z;
    z.x0 = complex<double>(10,20);
    std::cout << y*z << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think a way to do what you are looking for (return a `complex<T>` from `operator*`) because the `operator*` can't deduct the type automatically, so you have to specify the type, like in the example bellow:

```
a my_var1;
a my_var2;
complex<double> result = operator*<double>(my_var1, my_var2);
```

...or you can follow what @juanchopanza have suggested and do not use templates with `operator*`.